# getStaticPaths and dynamic folders in Next.js

Tags: next.js

I have a folder structure like this.

- .../[category]/products
- .../[category]/news

Im having som trouble with `getStaticPaths`. After the `[category]` slug there are no more dynamic routes, but Im having some trouble getting Next.js to properly pre-render the pages with `getStaticPaths`.

Anyone have any suggestions. It works with `fallback: "blocking"`, but thats not really how I want to do it.

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  return {
    paths: [
      {
        params: {
          category: "hiking"
        }
      },
      ...
    ],
    fallback: false,
  };
}
```

EDIT:
It doesnt matter what I put as the category in the url. /asdasd/news, /123123/news etc. all work as dynamic routes even when I specify exactly which categories to pre-render. And the index.js page returns 404 regardless of what I do. When I do category: "hiking", then routes like /asdasd/news should return a 404, unless I misunderstood this completely.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I dont get 404 on non declared routes and [category]/index.js is also 404.

Comment: _"I dont get 404 on non declared routes"_ - so what do you get instead? If the page is not declared under `paths` then it will 404 when using  `fallback: false`.

Comment: It doesnt matter what I put as the category in the url. `/asdasd/news`, `/123123/news` etc. all work as dynamic routes and return what they should even when I specify exactly which categories to pre-render. And the `index.js` page returns 404 regardless of what I do. When I do `category: "hiking"`, then routes like `/asdasd/news` should return a 404, unless I misunderstood this completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I was missing the `locale` property in `paths`.

```
paths: [
  {
    params: {
      category: "hiking"
    },
    locale: "en"
  }
],
```